# Rollover image PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

Is any change to obtain a rollover image effect on a single slide ? I mean whitout using custom show or hyperlink to another slide.I'am using PP 2010.

I was think at something like to hide an image behind another and on mouse over first image bring to front the second...but I don't found anything about this on the internet.Does anyone know any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas how to approach this

1. Create Shape1 and Shape2 at the same position. Add a show animation to Shape2 that is triggered by a click on Shape1
2. Create an action button that triggers a macro on mouse-over that will change the appearance of the button or makes another shape visible.

However, I am not sure if there is a way to reverse the effect.

Comment: I implemented something based on the first idea suggested by Paul.